# Visual C++ vector<char> puts numeric values in listbox

Tags: vector, char, c++-cli, ascii

I'm a C/Java/VBA guy who's new to C++... I need to take a vector of chars and populate the chars in a listbox (Visual Studio 2015) after pressing a button on the form.

When I try to do what seems natural (code below) the list box gets populated with the base-10 ASCII values instead of the characters. I've looked for ways to "force" listbox.Items.Add() to take it in as a character, but I've not had any luck. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
       std::vector<char> CDROMDrives{ 'A', 'B', 'C'};
       int i = 0;
       for (auto &c : CDROMDrives) {
           listBox1->Items->Add(c);
           i++;
       }
   }
```

[Here's what the list box looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEGU9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard note about the language: C++/CLI is intended as a bridge to allow C# or other .Net code to call C++ code. It is not intended as a primary development language. If you want to learn C++, I would use C++ with MFC as your GUI toolkit. If you want to learn managed code, I'd learn C# with either WinForms or WPF. If you've got Java/VBA experience, I'd go with C#.

That said:

You didn't say what GUI toolkit you're using, or what the type of `listBox1` is, but it's certainly a managed type of some sort. As such, you need to make a .Net [`System::String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to insert into the list box. A C++ `char` will be interpreted as an 8-bit integer, and a C++ `std::string` will not be interpreted as you'd like.

To convert to a string, cast it to the proper [managed type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), and then call the [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) method.

```
listBox1->Items->Add(((System::Char)c).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

65, 66, and 67 are the numeric values for 'A', 'B', and 'C' in ASCII. You need to make sure that your program is interpreting those values as `char`s and not `int`s. Try changing your loop condition to `for (char &c : CDROMDrives)` or casting to `char` before insertion to the list.

Comment: The vector has characters, so `auto` will deduce characters.

Comment: Then it may be that `ListBox` only accepts numeric types or `String`s. Try converting your `char` to a `String` before adding.